# Global Parameters Window in Meshlab

Tags: meshlab

I'm a new user, so this is probably a simple question, but in the Mac version of Meshlab, where do I find the Global Parameters Window? There is no Tools menu and the help search doesn't help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Under the meshlab->Preferences menu (Command+,)

[image]

Comment: That’s great. Thank you for taking the time to answer and help!